How to send dtmf and play audio stream like ivr using websocket send to freeswitch?
I'm building a call application using webrtc to freeswitch using java as sip gateway, I want to implement ivr function but don't know how to send dtmf to freeswitch via websocket on java. I cannot recreate INFO Sip Request from Invite Request.
I tried creating a string similar to invite but failed.

You already have webrtc, which supports sending DTMFs natively using:  dtmfSender.insertDTMF
See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Using_DTMF
JS example: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/dtmf/

you can generate dtmf tones wav or mp3 files using some packages like
https://github.com/tino1b2be/DTMF-Decoder
and than just play the file and freeswitch will detect it as if someone pressed the key
